# Makefile not setting variable

Tags: makefile

I have this recipe in my makefile:

```
fraglen=$(shell sed -r 's/,[^\t]+//g' $< | echo "`cut -f 3`/2" | bc)
macs2 [other arguments] --extsize $(fraglen)
```

The command to determine fraglen seems to be working fine, as make will output:

```
fraglen=102
```

But then the macs2 command is printed as:

```
macs2 [other arguments] --extsize
```

and then it fails with an error that the extsize argument expected one argument. Is it a problem with the fraglen variable being assigned, or the way I'm referencing it?

Comment: Are those lines in the context of a make target's recipe? If so then that's the problem. Each line in a recipe is (by default) run in its own shell session. (And in a recipe you don't need `$(shell command)` since you are already in a shell and can just use `$$(command)` but that's a different issue.)

Comment: Thanks, that's the problem then. So do I have to write to a temporary file and then cat it in backticks, or is there a better way?

Comment: I'm not sure what that `sed` command is doing exactly, but `echo "`cut -f 3`/2" | bc` could be written more simply as `awk {print $3/2}` (Of course, in a make recipe, you'd need to double the `$`.) Probably the `sed` could be eliminated as well by wrapping the transformation into the awk "program"

Comment: I want to base the extsize argument on the output of another program. The other program outputs a tab-delimited line and the value I want is the first in a series of comma-separated numbers in the third column. I want to set extsize to half of that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confusing make variables with shell variables. An assignment in a make recipe is assigning a *shell* variable. Unfortunately, in a make recipe, each line is executed independently in its own subshell, so shell environment variables are not preserved from one line to the next.

You can put the two lines together into a single logical line, so that they will both be executed in the same shell. You also need to change the second line so that it refers to a shell variable rather than a make variable:

```
target: ...
          fraglen=$(shell sed -r 's/,[^\t]+//g' $< | echo "`cut -f 3`/2" | bc) \
          macs2 [other arguments] --extsize $$fraglen
```

It's not necessary to use make's `$(shell ...)` construct, since you can let the shell do the computation (again, we double the $ so that it is passed to the shell).

```
target: ...
          fraglen=$$(sed -r 's/,[^\t]+//g' $< | echo "`cut -f 3`/2" | bc) \
          macs2 [other arguments] --extsize $$fraglen
```

Finally, you can simplify the shell expression by using, for example, awk:

```
target: ...
          fraglen=$$(awk -F'\t' '{ sub(/,.*/, "", $$3); print $$3/2 }' $<) \
          macs2 [other arguments] --extsize $$fraglen
```

(The awk program returns half of the first comma-separated value in the third tab-separated field of the single line of the input.) awk doesn't truncate to integers, so if it is possible that the number is odd, you need to use something like `printf "%d\n", $$3/2` instead of the print statement.)